# How to set selected on select element that is populated by Angular 2 *ngFor?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a `<select>` filter on my datatable. The datatable is populated with a list of competitions that are retrieved from a service. The select filter is populated with a list of sports, also retrieved from a service.

What I would like is to have an initial default option in the select element that would display all competitions, e.g. "Please select a Sport", and when the user selects a sport the competitions are filtered.

I have tried the following, but the select element is initially always empty. Is there a way to achieve this?

```html
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filterQuery">
   <option selected="selected" disabled>Please select a Sport</option>
   <option id="sport" *ngFor="let sport of sports" [ngValue]=sport>{{sport.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I think the approach Gunter suggests would work fine if filterQuery was of type string but filterQuery is of type Sport. The Pipe I have is

```html
export class SportFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(array: any[], query: Sport): any {
    if (query) {
        var result = array.filter(function (obj) {
            return obj.sport === query.id;
        });
        return result;
    }
    return array;
}
}
```

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assigning the value to `filterQuery`.

The `[]` part of `[(ngModel)]="filterQuery"` sets the initial value.

Just remove `selected="selected"`

Comment: I've updated my question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: I think this will work. `filterQuery` and what you use for `[ngValue]="..."` needs to match. If you want to select `<option>Please select a Sport</option>` you need to assign a value that can be used in `filterQuery`. I guess `<option [ngValue]="null">Please select a Sport</option>` with `this.filterQuery = null;` will work.

Comment: Worked a charm. Cheers Gunter!